# GUI tool for ubuntu that can access the ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu

Anyone know about a better Tool for GUI in ubuntu . please let me know

I want to work on GUI that can access the terminal

Comment: This is off topic because it's asking for software recommendations and off topic because it has little to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "a better tool" means for you but I know this can be achieved by sikuli.